# Why does ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter have a read method if it s means for outbound IO operations

Tags: netty, netty4

As far as I understand, in Netty `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` is meant for outbound IO operations: that is writes, but a class implementing `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` can also implement a `read` method, which seems incorrect to me, why should a component meant for writing have a read method.

The opposite component, that is `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` which is meant for inbound IO operations, ie reads, does not have a write method. This sounds correct.

Why does `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` makes it possible to implement a read method if it is supposed to push data out of the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` signals the willingness to read something from the socket as soon as there is something that can be read. It basically tells netty that we should do a read at some point.

Comment: but why should a component responsible for writing out data have the ability to "signal the willingness to read something from the socket as soon as there is something that can be read"

Comment: It is not only responsible for writing but also other "outbound" operations. This way you can implement back pressure etc.